# Compare two tables' data

Tags: sql

```
drop table #temp1
drop table #temp2

create table #temp1 (id int identity, A int, B int)
create table #temp2 (id int identity, A int, B int)

insert into #temp1 values (20, 1001)
insert into #temp1 values (20, 1001)
insert into #temp1 values (30, 1001)

insert into #temp2 values (20, 1001)
```

With the help of SQL, I need to find out that the 2nd and 3rd row in the #temp1 is not present in #temp2.

How to find it out?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)** operator:

```
SELECT id, a, b
FROM #temp1

EXCEPT

SELECT id, a, b
FROM #temp2 ;
```

---

You have to consider though something very serious. The `id` column gets its numbers automatically so they have no value for you. In a real example, you would probably had a `UNIQUE` constraint in the `(a, b)` column or some other combination defined as `PRIMARY KEY`. So, the example above wouldn't be valid. There would be only two rows inserted at `table1`, the 1st and the 3rd. The 2nd would be rejected as identical to the 1st one.

Comment: @Mark: No, you have a valid point. I had `SELECT a,b` at first, not really looking at the numbers there.